# VScode's Python Debug Console doesn't print Unicode Chinese Charactor Properly

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[Image to show the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQ0ry.png)Here is the code to illustrate the problem:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
text = u"严"
print text
```

If I run the code above in VSCode debug, it will prints "涓" instead of "严", which is the result of the first 2 byte (\xe4\xb8) of u"严" in UTF-8 (\xe4\xb8\xa5), decoded in gbk codec. \xe4\xb8 in gbk is "涓".

However if I run the same code in pycharm it prints "严" exactly as I expected. And it is the same If I run the code in powershell.

Wired the VSCode python debugger behaves different with python interpreter. How can I get the print result correct, I do not think add a decode("gbk") in the end of every text would be a good idea.

### My Environment data

- VS Code version: 1.21
- VSCode Python Extension version : 2018.2.1
- OS and version: Windows 10
- Python version : 2.7.14
- Type of virtual environment used : No

Answer (score 2):

1. For Windows users, in your System Variables, add `PYTHONIOENCODING` Variables,change its value to `UTF-8`, then restart vscode, this worked on my pc.
2. Modify `task.json` file in vscode, I am not sure if it will still work on version 2.0.
   You can find it here:[Changing the encoding for a task output](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_changing-the-encoding-for-a-task-output)
   or here in github:
   [Tasks should support specifying the output encoding](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3550)
3. add this before you start a py script:

   `import io
   import sys
   sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer,encoding='utf8')`

Comment: Setting system variable worked for me on Windows 10, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you open your python file in VS2017 you can do the following:

Go to:

1. File->
2. Save selected item as ->
3. > click on the down-arrow next to "Save button"
4. > clicking "Save With Encoding...
5. select the type of coding you need...
6. if .py already saved then overwrite file > select "yes"

> select for example : `"Chinese Simplified (GB18030) - Codepage 54936"`

Also, add the following on line 2 of your .py file:

`# -*- coding: gb18030 -*-` or `# -*- coding: gb2312 -*-`

Those encodings accept your 严 character.

Nice link to endocoder/decoder tester [here](http://string-functions.com/encodedecode.aspx).